# How to draw a circle in matlab with different range in X and Y axis

Tags: image, matlab, distance, geometry

I would like draw a circle in matlab.
However, my data X and Y  have different range axis.
I suspected that my values of X and Y have different range.
Could anyone advice me on how to improve the code?

```
%% Data set
    fData = [   3.6     79
            1.8     54
            3.333   74
            2.283   62
            4.533   85
            2.883   55
            4.7     88
            3.6     85
            1.95    51
            4.35    85
            1.833   54
            3.917   84
            4.2     78
            1.75    47
            4.7     83
            2.167   52
            1.75    62
            4.8     84
            1.6     52
            4.25    79
            1.8     51
            1.75    47
            3.45    78
            3.067   69
            4.533   74
            3.6     83
            1.967   55
            4.083   76
            3.85    78
            4.433   79
            4.3     73
            4.467   77
            3.367   66
            4.033   80
            3.833   74
            2.017   52
            1.867   48
            4.833   80
            1.833   59
            4.783   90  ]

[n,dim]=size(fData);
rng(1);
idx = randsample(n,2)
X = fData(~ismember(1:n,idx),:); % Training data
Y = fData(idx,:) 

for j = 1:length(Y)
     c = Y(j,:);
     pos = [c-r 2*r 2*r];
     rectangle('Position',pos,'Curvature',[1 1])
     %axis equal
end
```

How to make the both circle in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYT85.png) become a perfect circle?
Thank you

Comment: hi @Ash, it is still could not work and even squeezed

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is set the aspect ratio you want for your data, replacing the `%axis equal` line in you code with

```
daspect([1 1 1])
```

should do the job, as you can see in this example obtained with your code:

[image: example with your code]

Comment: Hi @Ash let me try

Comment: can you give me example code on how to set the range in in the picture

Comment: You can set them with xlim and ylim, e.g. xlim([0 10]). Anyway, this information is easy to find if you just google it.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: i have tried with xlim & ylim. So far, i m still looking for the solution

Comment: This was not your initial question. The initial question is solved. The range of the axes is another problem. Also, if you want help on that you have to describe the problem better than what you are currently doing. Why didn't xlim and ylim work?

Comment: Hi @Ash,this is the code as your suggested `for j = 1:length(Y)
     c = Y(j,:);
     pos = [c-r 2*r 2*r];
     rectangle('Position',pos,'Curvature',[1 1])
end
axis([0 10 40 100])
daspect([1 1 1])`  .. However, the graph plot becomes squeezed.

Comment: This works fine for me. Also, what is the value of `r` you are using? You haven't specified it in your code.

Comment: Hi @Ash, i put r = 0.3. Could you please share the code if you don't mind

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code line for line, even the one in the comments. Although, since I didn't have access to matlab this morning, I commented out the line where you specify the seed (`rng`), to run it with GNU Octave but I don't expect this to be relevant.

Comment: This is really surprising to me, and I expect that something silly is happening somewhere outside the code that you show, like the wrong script being called by mistake. Try to install GNU Octave and see if you can run it, that will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Well yes, but for this prupose I expect the behavior to be the same. I'm just hoping that this will help you find out what you are doing wrong with Matlab.

Comment: i modified part, it is improve little bit. But still has flaw.   `xx = (range(diff(X(:,1))))
yy = (range(diff(X(:,2))))
ratio = (xx / yy) /sqrt(2)
for j = 1:length(Y)
     c = Y(j,:)
     Yx = c(1)
     Yy = c(2)
     pos = [c-r (2*r) (2*r)/ratio];
     rectangle('Position',pos,'Curvature',[1 1])
end
axis([1 5.5 45 95])`